# Cannot open mailbox /var/mail/USER: Permission denied No mail for USER

Tags: 10.04, postfix

When i run the command. su - fmaster mail

I get the error:

```
Cannot open mailbox /var/mail/fmaster: Permission denied No mail for fmaster
```

also i sign in as fmaster. terminal -> mail.

```
/var/mail/fmaster: Permission denied No mail for fmaster
```

I tried to execute this code but i still get the same error..

```
sudo touch /var/mail/$USER
sudo chown $USER:mail /var/mail/$USER
sudo chmod o-r /var/mail/$USER
sudo chmod g+rw /var/mail/$USER
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /var/mail` command?

Comment: it shows list of users that i have created :
`-rw-rw---- 1       1006 mail    2037 2013-08-10 12:38 abuse
`

Comment: I know what it shows. And the output of `ls -l /var/mail/fmaster`?

Comment: `
-rw------- 1 fmaster      mail    2035 2013-08-10 00:16 fmaster
`

Comment: This is not ok, it sould be: `-rw-rw---- 1 fmaster mail 2035 2013-08-10 00:16 fmaster`. And what is the output of `groups fmaster`?

Comment: `fmaster : fmaster sudo`

Comment: As I said in my answer: `fmaster` is not a member of `mail` group and this is a problem!

Comment: I just checked on a FreeBSD system, a MacOS system, and a Linux system. In all cases, all mailboxes had `-rw-------`. The `/var/mail` directory itself was always `drwxrwxr-x  2 root  mail` or `drwxrwsr-x 2 root mail`

Answer (score 21):

The user `fmaster` is probably not in the `mail` group. You can run `groups` command to check in which groups you are.

To add `fmaster` to the group `mail` use the following command:

```
sudo adduser fmaster mail
```

And after run:

```
sudo chmod ug+rw /var/mail/fmaster
```

Comment: i dont think that is the problem i think this issue related to users permissions.

Comment: @cjayomer So, what is the output of `group` command?

Comment: the output of fmaster  `fmaster : fmaster sudo`

Comment: @cjayomer As I said, `fmaster` is not a member of `mail` group and this is a problem. See my new edits.

Comment: I made all that changes but when i sign in as fmaster and run mail command it shows the same problem

Comment: You broke it somehow. Try to [reinstall/reconfigure postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/email-services.html). Also consider to upgrade your Ubuntu version which is end of life.

Comment: When I tried this, the folder for my user in `/var/mail/USER` did not even exist.  Is there a more simple way to add a user to the mail group and also simultaneously create the mail directory with appropriate permissions?

Comment: I also had to run `sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /var/mail/ubuntu` where on AWS `ubuntu` is the default user.

Comment: I just tested on a FreeBSD system, a MacOS system, and a Linux system. My personal account is not in the "mail" group on any of them.

Comment: Wait, if you add all users to the mail group and give 660 permissions to the mailbox files, all users will be able to read each others emails.

Answer (score 14):

If you've followed Radu Rădeanu's advice, keep in mind that

```
/var/mail/fmaster
```

won't exist until it receives its first email.  So you should send fmaster an email before further troubleshooting.

Comment: lol, this is probably easier -- wasn't able to confirm answer.

Comment: This answer is a meeelion times better and more intuitive.  after doing this I was even able to fire up alpine (pine)!  works wonders for CLI.

Answer (score 7):

I confirmed that sending an email to the user for the first time did create the mail directory for the user.  Just do:

```
mail fmaster@localhost
```

`/var/mail/fmaster` directory will be created with the correct permision.
The user, fmaster, can then use the `mail` command to read the mail.

Comment: Can you blend in the answer with the OP, I am confused.

Comment: same as [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/869928/527764) in principle, but I'm upvoting both as this one explains much better than the original one.

Comment: How do I stop typing the body of the email lol

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the mail variable. The emails you may be sending could be directed to this directory.

MAIL=/home/your_user/Maildir

Then try the mail command again.

mail

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to sort out is which mail program you are using when you run `mail`.

Do this:

```
$ command -v mail               # (Similar to the old `which`.) You'll likely see:
/usr/bin/mail
```

Then see what this is:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/mail           # And now you'll likely see (at least for Debian):
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Feb 17  2019 /usr/bin/mail -> /etc/alternatives/mail
```

Then see where that is:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/mail  # And I get:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Dec 10 19:58 /etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
```

And finally check this out:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 218160 Nov 18  2020 /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
```

So when you are running `mail`, you are actually running `mail.mailutils`.  Also notice that it's owned by root, but everyone has permission to run read and execute it.

---

Now looking at the configuration documentation for the `mailutils` package, we see that there are many possible methods for configuration, including:

1. System wide configuration in `/etc/mailutils.conf`, or
2. User over-rides in `/home/[your-username]/.mail`, or even
3. Startup overrides with `mail --file /var/mail/[your-username]`

Settings from method 2 overrides method 1, and method 3 overrides both methods 2 and 1.

One important point is that the mailbox format doesn't have to be `mbox` (single large files with multiple messages in each file).  It can also be `mailbox` format (or a tree of individual files).  There are also other formats available, like `mh`.

For the first two options above you will likely want to use a URL

```
mailbox {
       # Create mailbox URL using PATTERN.  
       #   (preferred way of configuring mailbox locations)
       mailbox-pattern PATTERN;
}
```

Like this:

```
mailbox { mailbox-pattern "/var/mail/${user}"; }
```

---

Another important point is that your system has two places for your mailboxes:

- Incoming messages are in one place, typically `/var/mail/[username]`, and
- read messages are, depending on the mailbox format, in either:

  - `/home/[your-username]/mbox`   or
  - `/home/[your-username]/mailbox/*`.

---

If you're using any of the mailutils programs, you can see how your system is configured with:

```
$ mailutils info           # which gives you something like this:
VERSION=3.10
SYSCONFDIR=/etc
MAILSPOOLDIR=/var/mail
SCHEME=mbox
LOG_FACILITY=mail
...
```

---

Finally, don't confuse the two different uses of the term 'spool' as related to mail.  exim4 has what it calls a spool, which is where it holds messages waiting to be delivered, and then when you go to read emails some people say you're reading from the mail spool.  It is probably better to remember that you're reading from a mailbox, and that only exim4 has a spool.  For locally delivered messages exim4 reads a message from it's spool, and puts it into your mailbox, normally in `/var/mail/[your-username]` if you're using `mbox`.

Also note that you must be in the `mail` **group**, as others above have clarified.  What they didn't tell you was that you might need to reboot to make your addition to the mail group stick and show up when you open a terminal window.  Simply opening another terminal windows won't have you in that group, and logging out and re-logging in won't fix it either.

---

So now that you know which mailbox you're trying to read, you can look at it's permissions to see if you need to update them or not.

Comment: Your examples works perfect on Gentoo Linux. Thanks.